# How can you extract the given data from *Ng-for?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, ngfor

this is my HTML code

```
    <form class="form">
        <div class="formdiv" >
            <input id="login"class="name" [value]="user.login">

            <select class="authority" [value]="user.authority" >
                <option class="authority">ADMIN</option>
                <option class="authority">USER</option>
            </select>
            
            <button  mat-raised-button class="deleteBtn" type = "submit" (click)="deleteUser()">X</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

try to extract the data of the given div with this typescript code, but I always get only the first one back.

`console.log((<HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("login"))).value)`

How could it be resolved that it returns the ones I want?

Comment: You have to specify what exactly you want to achieve. It's not clear what is meant by "given div". You log statement does query for a specific ID, which is a single element. So from my point of view your code is working as expected.

Comment: <div class="container" *ngFor="let user of users">             This first line is missed

Comment: @Regnad09 Please edit your post and add the missing line. Also `id` attribute has to be unique in document.